# place images into an invisible grid with php / gdlib

Tags: php, image, grid, gd

I am trying to figure out how I can place a selection of about 100 different images of bricks and place them into a grid-like system.

It is to be used as a brick mixer where the user can select a wide range of different colored bricks and these will then be randomly placed in a specific grid.

This is my current code:

```
function BuildCustomBricks($myBricks) {

        $img = imagecreate(890,502);
        imagealphablending($img, true);
        imagesavealpha($img, true);

        foreach ($myBricks as $value) {
            $cur = imagecreatefrompng("/var/www/brickmixer/bricks/". $value .".png"); 
            imagealphablending($cur, true);
            imagesavealpha($cur, true);

            imagecopy($img, $cur, 0, 0, 0, 0, 125, 32);
            imagedestroy($cur);
        }

        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        imagepng($img);
    }
```

But, to no surprise, this isn't working the way I want.

I need it to place the brick images in a grid like this

```
brick | brick | brick | brick | brick | brick | brick |
  brick | brick | brick | brick | brick | brick | brick |
brick | brick | brick | brick | brick | brick | brick
```

etc. etc.

Is there any way I can achieve this, either by using gdlib and coords or f.x. jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution by setting static coords with imagecopy

```
imagecopy($img, $cur, 0, 0, 0, 0, 125, 32);
imagecopy($img, $cur, 130, 0, 0, 0, 125, 32);
imagecopy($img, $cur, 260, 0, 0, 0, 125, 32);
imagecopy($img, $cur, 390, 0, 0, 0, 125, 32);
imagecopy($img, $cur, 520, 0, 0, 0, 125, 32);
imagecopy($img, $cur, 650, 0, 0, 0, 125, 32);
imagecopy($img, $cur, 780, 0, 0, 0, 125, 32);
```